# Algebraic way of evaluating $\lim_{x\to \pi^-}\log(\sin(x))$?

Tags: limits

Is there an algebraic way of calculating the limit, $\lim_{x\to \pi^-}\log(\sin(x))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\;x\to\pi^-\;$ we have that $\;\sin x\to0^+\;$ , so $\;\log\sin x\;$ is well defined and thus

$$\lim_{x\to\pi^-}\log\sin x=\lim_{t\to0^+}\log t=-\infty$$

Comment: @Thanks Mark. I can see you yourself added a comment on this before my answer...;)

Comment: Yes, but I didn't provide any explanation and so have deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=\pi-h$ and compute the limit when $h\to 0^+$.

$$\begin{align}
\ln (\sin (x))&=\ln (\sin (\pi-h))\\\\
&=\ln (\sin (h))\\\\
&=\ln \left(h\frac {\sin (h)}{h}\right)\\\\
&=\ln (h)+\ln \left(\frac {\sin (h)}{h}\right) 
\end{align}$$

The limit is then

$$=-\infty+0=-\infty$$

Comment: I've reformatted to improve the quality of layout.